# django runscript error: no (valid) module for script 'main' found

Tags: python, django, backend

I wrote some code to run ... but i had a error while running my code.
So I tested some simple code like this... but it still doesn't work.

```html
def run():
  print("test")
```

Error message looks like:

[image: Error Message]

which says no (valid) module for script 'main' found.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and then [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Are you sure `main.py` script is located under `scripts` directory with `__init__.py` file? The **init** file is necessary so that folder package is picked up as python package. Checkout Runscript documentation [here](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html)

Comment: Then it works!!! Thanks for help!!!@!! I was new to django so I was really confused. Have a nice day <3 !

Answer (score 1):

**Running Extra scripts in Django**:

1. Create `scripts` directory in your root project, next to `manage.py`:

   ```
   $ mkdir scripts
   ```
2. Add an empty file ****init**.py** (double underscore) into your `/scripts` directory:

   ```
   $ touch scripts/__init__.py
   ```

   The init file is necessary so that the folder is picked up as a python package.

   **This is probably what you're missing.**
3. Add your scripts into `/scripts` directory:

   ```
   $ touch scripts/main.py
   ```
4. After you edited your `main.py` script, run it with:

   ```
   $ python manage.py runscript script-name
   ```

   Note: You shouldn’t include .py when specifying the script to run

Checkout [Runscript Documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html)